# Array of dictionaries convert to array of values only

Tags: javascript

I know it might be a simple task but i couldn't find proper solution for my task.

In JavaScript i have a data that's stored in array of dictionaries.

Example:

```
[{"car": "volvo", "model":"s40"},{"car": "audi", "model": "a4"}]
```

how i can convert this to get only values out and store them in to the array of arrays?

result:

```
[["volvo","s40"],["audi","a4"]]
```

Comment: `arr.map(e => Object.values(e))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the values from the objects directly with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
const
    data = [{ car: "volvo", model: "s40" }, { car: "audi", model: "a4" }],
    values = data.map(Object.values);

console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for the values of each Object so a `map` and `Object.values`

```js
let x = [{"car": "volvo", "model":"s40"},{"car": "audi", "model": "a4"}]
let y = x.map(e => Object.values(e))
console.log(y)
```